# Loop doesn't iterate an if statement more than once

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement, boolean-expression

So, the original problem that I am attempting to solve with this code is taking a string of varying length and then returning true only if that string contains between 1-3 "e's" and if there are any less or more return false. I wanted to individually extract the "e's" from the the given Strings and put them into a separate String and then test for how many "e's" that new String has to produce the correct Boolean values. Isolating the pol execution, by putting 3 "e's" into the empty string, I found that the code was returning false for everything that had at least 1 e. Nothing wrong there, but then I replaced the empty string with 2 "e's" and found that anything with at least 1 e was returning true, even if that String contained 50 "e's" in total. This means that the loop, when encountering the if statement, only iterates once and so only 1 e is added to String pol. My overarching question is: How do I get the loop to iterate the if statement according to the control.

Also don't worry about what comes before this code: Only know that this is Boolean

```
String pol = "";
String some;
for (int len = 0; len < str.length(); len = len + 1) {
    some = str.substring(len, len + 1);
    if (some.equals("e")) {
        pol = "" + some; 
    }
}
if (pol.equals("e") || pol.equals("ee") || pol.equals("eee")) 
    return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Should that be `pol += some;`? Also, please work on your code formatting. Your original code was very poorly formatted, making it very difficult for others to read and understand. I've corrected it for you, but we shouldn't have to be doing this for you.

Comment: Sorry, I've only just started using this site and it was tearing my code apart. Also, why does that work?

Comment: Because you are re-instancing pol to just "e"  every time.  Doing += adds to the existing value in the string variable instead.

Comment: I get it. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you encounter an `e` you **overwrite** `pol` instead of appending to it. Instead of

```
pol = "" + some;
```

You probably meant:

```
pol += some;
```

Regardless, appending to a string seems like a clunky way of accomplishing this task. It would be much easier to just increment an integer counter each time you encounter an `e`. Or even simpler with Java 8's streams:

```
long count = str.chars().filter(c -> c == 'e').count();
return count >= 1 && count <= 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to see how many 'e's are in a specific string.  There is a very simple way to do this called an [Enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).  Using this kind of loop, you can make this in very few lines:

```
String s = "Hello There!";
    int numOfEs = 0;
    boolean bool = false; 
    // loops through each character in the string s ('H', 'e', 'l', etc)
    for (Character c : s.toCharArray() /* Make String s a list of characters to iterate through*/) {
        if (c.equals('e') || c.equals('E')) // Make Uppercase and Lowercase Es both count 
            numOfEs++;
    }
    // Are there 3 or more E's?
    // If there aren't, the boolean will be false because I defined it to equal false.
    if (numOfEs >= 3)
        bool = true;
    System.out.println(bool + ": There are " + numOfEs + " e's.");
```

Answer (score 0):

All `poll = "" + some` does is put e in poll. Try `poll = poll + some`